# Don't print filenames in zgrep output when searching multiple files

Tags: linux, grep

When I use zgrep to search multiple .gz files, the output contains the filename in it. Sometimes I don't need it bcz I use some other scripts to parse the output.

I tried using "-h" option but it doesn't seem to work with zgrep.

This is how I use the command:

```
admin@mybox [11:16:56]> zgrep -Eh "\.ERR|\.WARNING|\.FATAL" messages.?.gz
messages.1.gz:Oct 14 10:02:06 .............................................
messages.2.gz:Oct 14 09:27:58 .............................................
```

Any idea how I can stop the filename from being printed?

Comment: How about piping the output into another grep which has the same match expression? Zgrep doesn't seem to have other options than grep's ones.

Comment: piping doesn't work either because the output piped to the second grep includes the filenames and the second grep assumes that the filenames are also part of the input. :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`-h` does not work for zgrep, but the equivalent 
`--no-filename`
option does. See
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=434429

**EDIT** As @ValarDohaeris suggests, the bug was apparently fixed in 1.6. I don't experience it in that version, while I still do in 1.5. I was not able to find such info in the changelog though.

Comment: It looks like this has been fixed now, `-h` is working in the version I have (`zgrep (gzip) 1.6`).

Comment: @ValarDohaeris Apparently, yes. I can confirm experiencing the bug in 1.5 and not in 1.6. I could not find this fix in the changelog though

Comment: On my system (`CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`), the `-h` option is working fine on `zgrep (gzip) 1.5`. Running bash `4.2.46(1)-release`. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯